Paired-lists and wave-like representation of integers
Inspired by Fourier analysis, where a function can be expressed in two equivalent forms (time-domain vs frequency-domain), I started thinking about the representation of integers in a similar way.

Primes
The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic tells us that every positive integer has a unique prime factorization. For example:
$$
60 = 2^2 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^1
$$
We can think of this as a pairing of the infinite list of primes $[2, 3, 5, 7, \ldots]$ with their corresponding exponents $[2, 1, 1, 0, 0, \ldots]$, where only finitely many exponents are non-zero.
(here's an idea to turn integers into a periodic function)

Bases
In base 10, the same number $60$ can also be expressed as:
$$
60 = 0 \cdot 10^0 + 6 \cdot 10^1 + 0 \cdot 10^2 + \cdots
$$
This corresponds to another pairing: the digits $[0, 6, 0, \ldots]$ with the powers of $10$, $[0, 1, 2, \ldots]$.

Both representations uniquely decompose the integer into fundamental components.
QUESTION
Is there a deeper mathematical framework or concept that unifies these paired list representations? Are there known results or connections between these decompositions?
I'm curious if others have thought about integers in this way and if this analogy has useful implications or generalizations.

The sequence of powers in the prime factorization gives a handy way to encode finite lists of nonnegative integers in a single positive integer. That might be used in, say, a proof of Goedel's Incompleteness Theorem or a slick proof that that set of finite sequences is countably infinite.
The sequence of digits in a given base is how we usually write numbers, so that's useful. Sometimes the sequence of digits helps you think of a trick for a puzzle/competition-style problem, e.g. connecting polynomials to base representations.
There are also connections like "in base 10, the only primes that can end in 0,2,4,5,6,8 are 2 and 5".
But I don't know that I'd say there's anything especially deep to mention here. Maybe another answer will prove me wrong.
